# Wingdings Font, Some Chars not shown correctly. Visible as Box

Tags: windows, winforms, fonts, wingdings

I am using the Wingdings Font for an winforms Application.

Since Windows 10 we have the Problem that some chars not shown correctly. 
In my Charmap they are shown correctly but when copy them out into "Editor" it's not working with all chars!
Word does not having issues displaying the chars correctly

[image]

Comment: I think you have to set the font on the form or control to match the font you're copying from. Segoe UI Symbol is the recommended font for windows 10. Or [Segoe MDL2 icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font).

Comment: As you see i am using the Windows Editor for the Test.